# Google App Engine - Read JSON file from application code

Tags: go, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, environment, app.yaml

In one of my deployed app engines I am getting the following error.

`error loading config file: open go-config.json: no such file or directory`

This is the snippet of go code in `handlers.go`

```
config := config{}
err := gonfig.GetConf("go-config.json", &config)
if err != nil {
    log.Printf("error loading config file: %v\n", err)
}
```

This is my `app.yaml` file

```
runtime: go114
service: finance
```

On the debugger for the app engine I can see that the project structure looks like this.

```
app engine:/
quantify
    app.yaml
    config.go
    go-config.json
    main.go
    handlers.go
    quantify
```

Why cant I read this file in my deployed application code? I've tried specifying handlers in my `app.yaml` a number of ways with no success.

Comment: @MuffinTop can you provide an example? Like just 

`runtime: go114
service: finance
upload: go-config.json`

Comment: What is the gonfig package?

Comment: @MuffinTop Its a JSON config file using this go package https://github.com/tkanos/gonfig

Comment: I was able to read the files from GAE root directory successfully using the standard `io/ioutil` package. Could you also provide us with the minimum reproducible code of your `main.go`?

Answer (score 1):

first you should find out the current path by `fmt.Println(os.Getwd())`

```
fmt.Println(os.Getwd())
config := config{}
err := gonfig.GetConf("go-config.json", &config)
if err != nil {
    log.Printf("error loading config file: %v\n", err)
}
```

then change "go-config.json" to a relarate path to the current path

Comment: I will try this, so I do not need any configurations in my app.yaml to specify this `.json` file ?

Comment: The path says `/srv` ? This honestly does not make sense according to the GAE/GCP documentation.

Comment: did you try like this `/srv/go-config.json`?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere Yeah, it still says `no such file or directory`

Comment: I can't reproduce the file reading error. Can you log the content of the file? like this `dat, _ := ioutil.ReadFile("/srv/go-config.json")          fmt.Print(string(dat))`